# Changing HTML tag with Props in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries, react-props, conditional-operator

I want to display my custom Tire element or simple div (depending on media queries) with different values on each call. But the ternary operator doesn't work (always displays Tire element, never div) and I'm getting "undefined" instead of string "1" that should be it's content.

Would anyone be so kind as to explain where I went wrong?

```
const Content = () => {
  const isDesktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 110em)')

  const displayTire = (props) => (isDesktop.matches
    ? <Tire className={`${props.title}`}>{`${props.content}`}</Tire>
    : <div className={`${props.title}`}>{`${props.content}`}</div>)

  displayTire.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    content: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  return (
        {displayTire('pneu1', '1')}
  )

export default Content
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually providing a title and content to the props of displayTire.

To do that, you should have done:

```
  return (
        {displayTire({ title: 'pneu1', content: '1'})}
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument you pass is `'pneu1'`.

This is assigned to the `props` variable.

You then read `props.title`.

Strings don't have `title` properties so the value is undefined.

---

Your prop types says that the first argument should be an **object** which contains two properties (`title` and `content`).

Pass an object that matches the definition instead of two plain strings.